# Modeling tool changer in Drake

Tags: drake

My real world robot has a station where it can release its current end-effector and latch on to a new one. I would like to model this in Drake, maybe with a MultibodyPlant where  there is a integer context variable that simply switches between tools. I would also be okay with having a LeafSystem contain MultibodyPlants inside (one for each tool), and I guess a context variable that multiplexes the scene graph output port to the correct MultibodyPlant. Is this a standard thing to do in Drake? If so, is there some easy example code I can adapt for this purpose? If not, what is the Drake way to model tool changer devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the best workflow available today for simulation would be to use the ["joint locking"] feature (https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_joint.html#a50c7f850050d4a94641ed72dd2d1968f).  It would go something like this:

- Add a joint (probably a [quaternion floating joint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_quaternion_floating_joint.html)) with your end effector as the parent and the tool as the child -- for all possible tools.
- All joints start unlocked. The tools will effectively be floating bodies, except that their DOFs will be in coordinate relative to the end-effector.
- When you move the end-effector to the changer, you lock the tool to the end-effector. Now they will move together as if welded.
- Currently I believe you'll need to deal with the lock/unlock logic outside of the simulation... for instance you might have the simulation loop:

```
while True:
   simulator.AdvanceTo(context.get_time() + 1.0)
   # maybe lock/unlock joints here
```

We will have a slightly more flexible solution available soon using [weld constraints](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19608) in the contact solver.

Comment: I have been thinking about this more. If I add these joints, then I will end up increasing the configuration space dimension of my plant (because each tool now contributes a quaternion, whereas before it was welded). Will this affect consumers like KinematicTrajectoryOptimization or IrisInconfigurationSpace? In particular, I would want IrisInConfigurationSpace's HPolyhedrons to have only the number of dimension of my robot, and I can manually record which tool was supposed to be attached.

Comment: I agree.  For use in IRIS-NP as it is today, you'll probably do better with your "family of MultibodyPlants", one for each tool configuration.  We have an active feature request for supporting [in-memory rebuilding of MultibodyPlant](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18162), but for now the recommendation is just to parse separately from disk for each of your MBP variants.